# How to delete/renew expired certificates from Root certificate module in Sun Java System Web Server 6.1

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, sun, sunone, root-certificate

I have several expired certificates in Built-in root certificate module in Sun Java System Web Server 6.1. Is there anyway that I can delete/renew those expired certificates from there?

Comment: Did you go through the admin guide ? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/820-5704/bhafb/index.html

Comment: yeah, it just tells me to delete libnssckbi.so entry from alias file to disable the root certificate module, and to put the libnssckbi.so back to alias sub directory from bin/https/lib directory to enable it. But I don't want to disable the root certificate module, instead I just want to delete/renew expired certificate only.

Comment: Well if you can't delete you can upgrade. Replace libnssckbi.so with one from the latest version.

Comment: That is a good idea, but then I need to download a new version of SunOne and install and get that extension from there.

Comment: Not necessarily , you can get latest RPMs from Mozilla NSS : http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libnssckbi.so&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=

Comment: yeah it may work. I just downloaded the below RPM and extracted the libnssckbi.so from there and copied the SunOne. It just updated the certificate listing with more expired certificates (which means this is working and the libnssckbi.so was an old one)

ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/mageia/distrib/cauldron/i586/media/core/release/libnss3-3.17.3-3.mga5.i586.rpm

Comment: Now I need to find a new RPM which offers the newest libnssckbi.so,

Comment: replaced it with the latest from there, and also I have installed iPlant 7 (the latest SunOne Server) and got the so file from there and replaced, but now I can see more expired certificates. how this could be? :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66727/discussion-between-user360321-and-roshith).